# Typescript error TS2345 on regular express code

Tags: express, typescript

I have express typings installed with typescript 1.8.10 and this code:

```
app.use( function( err, req, res, next ) {
    if ( err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN' ) {
        return next( err )
    }

    // handle CSRF token errors here
    res.status( 403 )
    res.send( 'form tampered with' )
} )
```

which is a middleware code to catch csrf errors produces these errors:

> Error:(130, 10) TS2345: Argument of type '(err: Request, req:
>   Response, res: NextFunction, next: any) => any' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'string | RegExp | (string | RegExp)[]'.  Type
>   '(err: Request, req: Response, res: NextFunction, next: any) => any'
>   is not assignable to type '(string | RegExp)[]'.  Property
>   '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '(err: Request, req: Response,
>   res: NextFunction, next: any) => any'.
>
> Error:(131, 14) TS2339: Property 'code' does not exist on type
>   'Request'.
>
> Error:(136, 9) TS2339: Property 'status' does not exist on type
>   'NextFunction'.
>
> Error:(137, 9) TS2339: Property 'send' does not exist on type
>   'NextFunction'.

How to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a an issue with your types, so make sure you run `npm install` to ensure you have all the correct dependencies.